# Sorting the values in a dataframe where the column contain list of tuples

Tags: pandas, dataframe, metrics, recommendation-engine

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvRy.png)

[values which needs to be sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t8tA.jpg)

that column contain list of tuples values ..

for ex : {1100. [ ( a, 4) , (b, 6)
and there are n customers such ....
op needs to be    6,b  4,a

The query is to sort based on the recommended games rank..

I have used the below code

```py
sort_rank = sorted(recommend_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
recommend_games_df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sort_rank)
```

but this is failing ..

Comment: In the recommended games rank column , there are list of tuples value , so for each string( which is a game and there is a rank associated to it ) so based on that rank i need to sort which is second argument --> refer the df picture..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
recommend_games_df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(recommend_dict )
recommend_games_df=recommend_games_df.sort_values(recommend_games_df.columns[1])
```

Comment: it didn't work, as you can find the list of tuples , so based on that value i need to sort it .   for ex [( a,4) , (b,7)] --> the op needs to be [(7,b),(4,a)]